# Redirect to new domain within sites-available apache

Tags: apache-2.2, redirect

I'm moving a website from www.myolddomain.com to www.mynewdomain.com however I'm trying to do the following:

If someone goes to www.myolddomain.com they will be redirected to www.mynewdomain.com/pageA

If someone goes to www.myolddomain.com/pageB they will be redirected to www.mynewdomain.com/pageB

I've implemented a redirect at the moment like so in my `sites-available` file:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^myolddomain.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.myolddomain.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mynewdomain.com/$1 [L,R=301,NC]
```

It works great as it points the old domain to the new domain and preserves the path but I'd like if someone hits the root of the old domain they're redirected to a specifc page.

I hope someone out there could advise me on this and hope my question is clear enough.

I'm doing the redirects in the server config files as I don't want to use a `.htaccess` file for security reasons.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add this line just after the two `RewriteCond` and before your RewriteRule:

```
RewriteRule ^/$ http://www.mynewdomain.com/pageA [L,R=301]
```

If this rule doesn't match then the original will be evaluated. It is important that this rule be before your original rule.

Regards

Paolo B.

Comment: Thank you so much for that answer, very helpful and I'll remember that in future. It worked perfectly